# Increase stack size in ECLiPSe/prolog/fd

Tags: prolog, stack, overflow, constraint-programming

We have to solve the [liars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liar_paradox) problem in prolog, in several environments with constraints (ECLiPSe ic, ECLiPSe fd, SWI-prolog, GNU-prolog, NaxosSolver, etc.). I have used tail recursion (I think) and as many cuts as I could think of(that way I guess the resolution tree is not getting as big as it could be. If requested, I can post my code.

When the data number becomes 10000-50000, I receive a stack overflow in fd and ic in ECLiPSe and in SWI-prolog the program runs forever. So I would like to **increase the size of the stack in ECLiPSe**, but I can not see how.
I tried to write in the 1st line of my code this:

```
:-set_flag(local_stack_allocated, 512).
```

, but it says out of range.

See what eclipse says, which might be helpful:
*** Overflow of the global/trail stack in spite of garbage collection!
You can use the "-g kBytes" (GLOBALSIZE) option to have a larger stack.
Peak sizes were: global stack 128832 kbytes, trail stack 5312 kbytes

Comment: Um... did you try adding `-g 512` to the command line like it suggests?

Comment: How? I am trying like this
-g 512,readclaims("liars50000.txt", I),liars(I, Sol).
but I get string stream 27: syntax error: unexpected token

Comment: By the time you get to `?-`, Prolog is already running and it is too late. You need to pass the command line arguments to Eclipse. Edit whatever menu or icon you use to run Eclipse and add the command line arguments there. Not in your program. Before.

Comment: I am trying for days, but I just can not succeed in increasing the size. I have searched all the toolbar for eclipse. I am not sure what you mean by editing the icon. :/ Thanks for your answers though :)

Comment: Using Eclipse has lobotomized your computer and amputated your limbs. Run SWI outside Eclipse from the command line like so: `swipl -g 512`. That's literally all you have to do. If you need help figuring out how to do that, go to the nearest computer lab and shout "I need help with Unix!" and someone will assist you.

Comment: I am on Windows. I run SWI and got ERROR: Syntax error: Operator expected
ERROR: swipl -g 
ERROR: ** here **
ERROR: 512.
However, I can not see how SWI affects Eclipse and I have to use Eclipse.

Comment: It's probably hopeless, but I want to mention that it should be '-g 512000', not just '-g 512'

Comment: I tried to write it before I run the program, but the command line says:
string stream 27: syntax error: unexpected token
| -g 512000
|         ^ here

Tried to insert it with set_flag into the code too, but as Daniel said, this will not work.

Comment: @DanielLyons: I go in a local computer shop and shout something about Linux they will call the neuro - or police, if I'm less lucky...

Comment: Beware !!! Cuts are dangerous !!! You could be wounded !!! Why don't you explain your approach to solving instead of twiddling with stack size ? I take for sure your program it's looping...

Comment: @CapelliC: English language barrier. A lab is something universities provide to students. A shop is a business that sells machines.

Comment: @CapelliC sorry but now I saw your comment. My program works, but for N = 50000 it gets a stack overflow. I would be glad to show some code, but this will be a bit out off topic I guess :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, from error message text I'm assuming that you mean [ECLiPSe](http://www.eclipseclp.org/) constraint logic programming system, not Eclipse IDE.

Second, how do you start ECLiPSe? How do you load your code into ECLiPSe?

Try this (you said you are on Windows):

1. Open command line from the folder where your ECLiPSe source file (say, 'myprogram.ecl') exists. For instructions look at this page: http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/how-open-windows-command-prompt-any-folder.htm
2. In the command line put `eclipse -g 512000` and press ENTER.
3. Load your program using `[myprogram].` (put name of your ECLiPSe source file instead of 'myprogram').
4. Execute queries as usual.

But I suspect that your program just runs forever and eats all memory, so all this probably won't help in the end.

EDIT. Updated instructions for TkECLiPSe:

1. In TkECLiPSe in menu choose Tools -> TkECLiPSe Preference Editor.
2. In preference window find option "Global/trail stack size (in megabytes)" and set it to 512.
3. Save preferences and close TkECLiPSe.
4. Next time you run TkECLiPSe stack size will be set to 512 Mb.

Comment: Win7. I just click on the icon and hit File->Compile. Then I execute queries.

I have the source files (which have as extension .pl, I tried to use .ecl but same behavior) in Documents/Prolog, where the eclipse has been installed on a different subfile on "Computer". I also have a folder in the start menu.
I tried from all three locations, opened the cmd, putted what you said, but I got this:
'eclipse' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Since it's running for inputs with N = 10000, I think we can give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: He's quite clearly running SWI-Prolog from some sort of Eclipse Prolog mode. In other words, yes, the IDE, not ECLiPSe.

Comment: @DanielLyons, just google "Overflow of the global/trail stack in spite of garbage collection!". It's ECLiPSe CLP. And I've seen this very error before.

Comment: And SWI-Prolog '-g' flag has different meaning: "-g goal          Initialisation goal".

Comment: Either way, they can't get to the command line to do anything about it. Teach 'em how to land a plane and perform neurosurgery while you're at it, you'll have the same luck.

Comment: It would be really great if they were running ECLiPSe from Eclipse, for what it's worth.

Comment: Bet they're using [Prolog Development Tools](http://prodevtools.sourceforge.net/) but it doesn't claim to support ECLiPSe (though it does support SWI).

Comment: Sergey, your asnwer was really good. Yesterday, I was just too tired to resolve the issue. I should type TkEclipse.lnk (this is the corresponding "thing" I click on the start menu to run the app.
So, I type TkEclipse.lnk -g 512000 and a pop-up error-window appears:
Bad geometry specifier "512000"
Any ideas? If I type only TkEclipse.lnk, then the app starts, like if I had clicked on the icon on the start menu.

Comment: @SergeyDymchenko that's it. I got an overflow again. Since I am greedy, I increase the size of the local stack to 512. Bad idea! Now, when I start TkEclipse, I get an error window, which says:|
Cannot reserve stack space in alloc_stack_pairs()
and it does not allow me to do nothing. I reinstalled, restarted the laptop but nothing. However, you helped already too much and I fell a little strange, so if this too much for you to answer, just let go :)

Comment: @user2411320 I don't have Windows to check, but there should be a file in your user home directory called 'tkeclipserc' or similar. Edit it or just delete to reset preferences for TkECLiPSe.

Comment: In Local Disk/Program Files(x86)/Eclipse 6.0 is where I went and searched (with brute force, but found nothing which had rc at the end. As a matter of fact, most of the "things" there, had an extension. My source files, are in Documents/Prolog, but that's irrelevant I think. Can you help me track down this file?

Comment: @user2411320 I've found that on Windows preferences saved into the registry into HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\IC-Parc\\ECLiPSe (see http://eclipseclp.org/archive/eclipse-clp-users/1425.html). So you need to run Windows Registry Editor and edit or delete 'globalsize' value.

Comment: That did the trick. You are simple perfect. If there is anything I can do to increase your rating/ reputation here, please let me know ;)